# keypool and restoring from backup

Tags: wallet.dat

I have a wallet running on a raspbery pi and the SD card hit the skids, fortunatley I have a backup of the .iso from 1 month ago so I have recovered the entire state as of that time.

My only concern is over the keypool.  I had increasead it to 1000 because I was testing issung a lot of transactions, my keypool was down to around 800 before my issue required the backup.  Now my keypool is at 970 (as it was a month ago) and Im trying to figure out if thats going to cause a problem when a key that is already used in an existing TX is to be used again?

Answer (score 1):

Try **not** to reuse keys/addresses.

Just call `getnewaddress` 200-times (RPC call in a loop).

Maybe call `keypoolrefill` afterwards (and do a backup again if you don't use HD [Core >=0.14]).